# Delete all nodes starting and ending with specific nodes in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to delete several nodes or you can call it a "Trace" that start or end with specific nodes.

The data looks like this

DATA1 = A, B, C, D

DATA2 = A, C, B, D

DATA3 = A, D, B, C

DATA4 = A, D, C, B

What i meant by deleting a trace that start or end with specific nodes is, i want to delete all traces that do not start with node A or do not end with node D. So, with 4 data example i mention earlier, i want to delete DATA3 and DATA4 with 1 query.

Comment: I didn't get your question, can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to find certain paths and delete all the nodes on those:

```
MATCH path = (start:Trace {id:'A'})-[*4:NEXT]->(end:Trace)
WHERE NOT end.id = 'D'
FOREACH (node IN nodes(path) | DETACH DELETE node)
```